# Save UML diagrams in XMI file

Tags: uml, xmi

How I can save my UML **2.5** diagrams in XMI files. I read specifications for UML and XMI but I not enough know English to clearly understand it.

I very need in example of xmi file that contains some UML 2.5 diagram. But I cannot find so samples. Or some documentation which will be easier than OMG specifications. Are some samples of XMI or docs exist?

Comment: Writing XMI serialization by hand can be a very daunting task, and I would not advise to do it unless you must. From what tool/language do you want to save it? Because for example Java has tools for it (such as https://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2 )

Comment: Also since your question is too broad (and asks for off-site resources) it will very likely be removed as not constructive.

Comment: Just on Russian forums no one replied me

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to understand generated files

Answer (score 2):

[XMI](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/) is a standard to exchange UML **models**, not diagrams.

For a standard to exchange diagrams see [UML Diagram Interchange](http://www.omg.org/spec/UMLDI/)

Nonetheless many UML tool vendors have added diagram specifications in their XMI export. Sadly these are all custom extensions of XMI, so it's unlikely that another tool will be able to read interprete those correctly.

Comment: Maybe, I wrote incorrect my question. But I know how to insert into xmi additional information about diagram and etc to draw it on screen after loading. But I have problem with UML objects and their declarations, for example how to present class and association in xmi format as UML object, not drawable entity.

Comment: How can you know about additional diagram information, but not about the basics such as classes and associations? There's a speficiation document on the omg site. Start from there.

Comment: Because of it is only extension of xmi. I wrote about information which need for drawer, for example background color, positions, sizes and etc.

Comment: I already read omg specs. But there is almost nothing about object presentation in xmi. Only few examples that cover base. So I asked where I can find more expanded examples or documentations.

Comment: I will glad if you can post some xmi that will contain class diagram with custom datatype and two linked classes. It can very help me to understand principals of UML object presentation in xmi